# Install CiviVounteer 4.5 - 1.4.1

Tags: installation, error, civivolunteer

I am using CiviCRM 4.6.7 installed on CMS WordPress version 4.3.1 and I'd like to install the extention CiviVolunteer. From Administer > System Settings > Extentions, I choose CiviVolunteer version 4.5-1.4.1 but the system shows me this error: "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Multi-select is not valid option for field html_type [image]

Can you help me?

Comment: This is a good question!  To solve your problem, we'll need to see the expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: Is civivolunteer is extension version is compatible with your civicrm version?

Comment: As Jon G 2 suggested, I set "yes" to "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace" and result is the following:

Comment: As Jon G 2 suggested, I set "yes" to "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace" and result is the following:  CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "'Multi-select' is not a valid option for field html_type"

#0 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader.php(491): civicrm_api3("customField", "create", (Array:7))
#1 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader.php(54): CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader->createVolunteerContactCustomFields(13)

Comment: #2 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader/Base.php(248): CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader->install()
#3 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/volunteer.civix.php(50): CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader_Base->onInstall()
#4 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/volunteer.php(123): _volunteer_civix_civicrm_install()

Comment: #5 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager/Module.php(78): volunteer_civicrm_install()
#6 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager/Module.php(50): CRM_Extension_Manager_Module->callHook(Object(CRM_Extension_Info), "install")
#7 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php(233): CRM_Extension_Manager_Module->onPreInstall(Object(CRM_Extension_Info))
#8

Comment: #8 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(195): CRM_Extension_Manager->install((Array:1))
#9 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(345): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
#10 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(164): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#11

Comment: #11 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", "Next")
#12 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#13 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#14

Comment: #14 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#15 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(395): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#16 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(174): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(1, NULL)
#17

Comment: #17 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(125): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#18 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#19 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#20

Comment: #20 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#21 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1189): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#22 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#23

Comment: #23 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-includes/plugin.php(503): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#24 /var/www/clients/client101/web131/web/wp-admin/admin.php(236): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#25 {main}
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
'Multi-select' is not a valid option for field html_type

Comment: Sorry for all these messages...I can't send a screenshot as I?d like.....